# Thumbs.db does not always show up in image folders

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, thumbs.db

For some folders, Thumbs.db does now show up even though I am showing hidden folders/files and always showing extensions. How do I get it to always be displayed while using Windows Explorer?

Also, the file shows up when I use the command prompt `dir /a` but if I do `del Thumbs.db` it says it does not exist. But if I do `del /A Thumbs.db` it will delete it properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uncheck `"Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)"` in the Folder Options

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to preview mode so that Windows creates the Thumbs.db file.

Comment: The file already exists but it's not being displayed. I can open it using Notepad++ (but I have to manually type the name because it doesn't show up in the file selection)

Comment: Are you sure that the option of showing hidden files is enable on all folders? When you go to enable it press the button "Apply to all folders"

Comment: Yes. There is a hidden folder in the directory that I can see just fine.

Comment: try to delete the Thumbs.db file from the command and lets windows create another one. Maybe works

Comment: after that try to disable showing windows file and re-enable it

Comment: Deleted it but it didn't create a new one after putting it in Thumbnail view. So strange.

Comment: I unchecked "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" and that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also going to disable the Thumbnail caching to try and get rid of these stupid files entirely.